# How to automatically generate a publication list on a Quarto website?

Tags: r, bibtex, quarto, bibliography, biblatex

Is there an (easy) way to automatically generate a publication list (from a bib-file) on Quarto website using R?

I plan to build a new academic website using quarto. To reduce the weekly/monthly maintenance load, I intend to structure/organize/build this page to fulfill multiple purposes at once. The site should not only be a classic academic website but also provide the basics for my CV. Hence, I want to generate the CV directly from this website. That seems to be pretty easy using Quarto and combining the .qmd files for a PDF.

However, I also want to use a bib-file of my publications to automatically generate a publication list. I want to list them categorized by type (@article or @book) and in descending chronological order (2022, 2021, 2020).

In addition, I want to add two other features to this list. First, I want to add numbers per category to each publication, so that the first publication in the category @book receives [1], the second [2] and so on. Second, I want to highlight (bold text) my name (e.g., John Doe) when there are multiple authors for a publication.

Is there an easy way to use R in Quarto for getting such an output?

I have attached some example bib-file entries:

```
@article{Doe2022b,
    author = {Doe, John},
    date-added = {2022-11-20 09:36:34 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-11-20 09:37:52 +0100},
    doi = {10.1109/5.771073},
    journal = {Daily Prophet},
    number = {3},
    pages = {1-25},
    title = {I still know it better},
    volume = {25},
    year = {2020},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1109/5.771073}}

@article{Doe2020,
    author = {Doe, Jane and Doe, John},
    date-added = {2022-11-20 09:34:29 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-11-20 09:36:30 +0100},
    doi = {10.1109/5.771073},
    journal = {Daily Prophet},
    number = {1},
    pages = {18-35},
    title = {We know it better},
    volume = {23},
    year = {2020}}

@book{Doe2021,
    address = {Hogwarts},
    author = {Doe, John},
    date-added = {2022-11-20 09:34:11 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-11-20 09:34:19 +0100},
    publisher = {Flourish and Blotts},
    title = {My first Book},
    year = {2021}}

@book{Doe2022,
    address = {Hogwarts},
    author = {Doe, John},
    date-added = {2022-11-20 09:32:15 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-11-20 09:33:56 +0100},
    publisher = {Flourish and Blotts},
    title = {My second Book},
    year = {2022}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any existing tool that does what you need. If you want to build it yourself, then use Quarto's Lua support to do so.

For example, to generate a list off all books, you'd write a Lua file like this:

```lua
-- This is `books-section.lua`
local function is_book (ref)
  return ref.type == 'book'
end

function Pandoc (doc)
  local references = pandoc.utils.references(doc)
  local books = references:filter(is_book)
  doc.meta.references = books
  doc.meta.bibliography = nil -- ensure that only books will be used
  doc.blocks = pandoc.Blocks{
    pandoc.Header(1, 'Books'),
    pandoc.Div({}, 'refs')
  }

  return pandoc.utils.citeproc(doc)
end
```

and then use it to generate a "Book" section with

```
quarto pandoc -L books-section.lua my-bibliography.bib \
    --to=markdown-citations -o books.qmd
```

The Lua integration is quite powerful, so you might be able to do everything you need and to integrate the whole process into the normal website generation. See the [Quarto docs on Lua development](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/lua.html) for more details.